# How to add a member function to an existing Python object?

Tags: python, oop, object

Previously I created a lot of Python objects of class A, and I would like to add a new function `plotting_in_PC_space_with_coloring_option()` (the purpose of this function is to plot some data in this object) to class A and use those old objects to call `plotting_in_PC_space_with_coloring_option()`.

An example is:

```
import copy
import numpy as np
from math import *
from pybrain.structure import *
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.datasets.supervised import SupervisedDataSet
import pickle
import neural_network_related


class A(object):
    """the neural network for simulation"""
    '''
    todo:
        - find boundary
        - get_angles_from_coefficients
    '''

    def __init__(self, 
                 index, # the index of the current network
                 list_of_coor_data_files, # accept multiple files of training data
                 energy_expression_file, # input, output files
                 preprocessing_settings = None, 
                 connection_between_layers = None, connection_with_bias_layers = None,
                 PCs = None,  # principal components
                 ):

        self._index = index
        self._list_of_coor_data_files = list_of_coor_data_files
        self._energy_expression_file = energy_expression_file

        self._data_set = []
        for item in list_of_coor_data_files:
            self._data_set += self.get_many_cossin_from_coordiantes_in_file(item)

        self._preprocessing_settings = preprocessing_settings
        self._connection_between_layers = connection_between_layers
        self._connection_with_bias_layers = connection_with_bias_layers
        self._node_num = [8, 15, 2, 15, 8]
        self._PCs = PCs

    def save_into_file(self, filename = None):
        if filename is None:
            filename = "network_%s.pkl" % str(self._index) # by default naming with its index

        with open(filename, 'wb') as my_file:
            pickle.dump(self, my_file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

        return 


    def get_cossin_from_a_coordinate(self, a_coordinate):
        num_of_coordinates = len(a_coordinate) / 3
        a_coordinate = np.array(a_coordinate).reshape(num_of_coordinates, 3)
        diff_coordinates = a_coordinate[1:num_of_coordinates, :] - a_coordinate[0:num_of_coordinates - 1,:]  # bond vectors
        diff_coordinates_1=diff_coordinates[0:num_of_coordinates-2,:];diff_coordinates_2=diff_coordinates[1:num_of_coordinates-1,:]
        normal_vectors = np.cross(diff_coordinates_1, diff_coordinates_2);
        normal_vectors_normalized = np.array(map(lambda x: x / sqrt(np.dot(x,x)), normal_vectors))
        normal_vectors_normalized_1 = normal_vectors_normalized[0:num_of_coordinates-3, :];normal_vectors_normalized_2 = normal_vectors_normalized[1:num_of_coordinates-2,:];
        diff_coordinates_mid = diff_coordinates[1:num_of_coordinates-2]; # these are bond vectors in the middle (remove the first and last one), they should be perpendicular to adjacent normal vectors

        cos_of_angles = range(len(normal_vectors_normalized_1))
        sin_of_angles_vec = range(len(normal_vectors_normalized_1))
        sin_of_angles = range(len(normal_vectors_normalized_1)) # initialization

        for index in range(len(normal_vectors_normalized_1)):
            cos_of_angles[index] = np.dot(normal_vectors_normalized_1[index], normal_vectors_normalized_2[index])
            sin_of_angles_vec[index] = np.cross(normal_vectors_normalized_1[index], normal_vectors_normalized_2[index])
            sin_of_angles[index] = sqrt(np.dot(sin_of_angles_vec[index], sin_of_angles_vec[index])) * np.sign(sum(sin_of_angles_vec[index]) * sum(diff_coordinates_mid[index]));  
        return cos_of_angles + sin_of_angles

    def get_many_cossin_from_coordinates(self, coordinates):
        return map(self.get_cossin_from_a_coordinate, coordinates)

    def get_many_cossin_from_coordiantes_in_file (self, filename):
        coordinates = np.loadtxt(filename)
        return self.get_many_cossin_from_coordinates(coordinates)

    def mapminmax(self, my_list): # for preprocessing in network
        my_min = min(my_list)
        my_max = max(my_list)
        mul_factor = 2.0 / (my_max - my_min)
        offset = (my_min + my_max) / 2.0
        result_list = np.array(map(lambda x : (x - offset) * mul_factor, my_list))
        return (result_list, (mul_factor, offset)) # also return the parameters for processing

    def get_mapminmax_preprocess_result_and_coeff(self,data=None):
        if data is None:
            data = self._data_set
        data = np.array(data)
        data = np.transpose(data)
        result = []; params = []
        for item in data:
            temp_result, preprocess_params = self.mapminmax(item)
            result.append(temp_result)
            params.append(preprocess_params)
        return (np.transpose(np.array(result)), params)

    def mapminmax_preprocess_using_coeff(self, input_data=None, preprocessing_settings=None):
        # try begin    
        if preprocessing_settings is None:
            preprocessing_settings = self._preprocessing_settings

        temp_setttings = np.transpose(np.array(preprocessing_settings))
        result = []

        for item in input_data:
            item = np.multiply(item - temp_setttings[1], temp_setttings[0])
            result.append(item)

        return result
        # try end    

    def get_expression_of_network(self, connection_between_layers=None, connection_with_bias_layers=None):
        if connection_between_layers is None:
            connection_between_layers = self._connection_between_layers
        if connection_with_bias_layers is None:
            connection_with_bias_layers = self._connection_with_bias_layers

        node_num = self._node_num
        expression = ""
        # first part: network
        for i in range(2):
            expression = '\n' + expression
            mul_coef = connection_between_layers[i].params.reshape(node_num[i + 1], node_num[i])
            bias_coef = connection_with_bias_layers[i].params
            for j in range(np.size(mul_coef, 0)):
                temp_expression = 'layer_%d_unit_%d = tanh( ' % (i + 1, j) 

                for k in range(np.size(mul_coef, 1)):
                    temp_expression += ' %f * layer_%d_unit_%d +' % (mul_coef[j, k], i, k)

                temp_expression += ' %f);\n' % (bias_coef[j])
                expression = temp_expression + expression  # order of expressions matter in OpenMM

        # second part: definition of inputs
        index_of_backbone_atoms = [2, 5, 7, 9, 15, 17, 19];
        for i in range(len(index_of_backbone_atoms) - 3):
            index_of_coss = i
            index_of_sins = i + 4
            expression += 'layer_0_unit_%d = (raw_layer_0_unit_%d - %f) * %f;\n' % \
            (index_of_coss, index_of_coss, self._preprocessing_settings[index_of_coss][1], self._preprocessing_settings[index_of_coss][0])
            expression += 'layer_0_unit_%d = (raw_layer_0_unit_%d - %f) * %f;\n' % \
            (index_of_sins, index_of_sins, self._preprocessing_settings[index_of_sins][1], self._preprocessing_settings[index_of_sins][0])
            expression += 'raw_layer_0_unit_%d = cos(dihedral_angle_%d);\n' % (index_of_coss, i)
            expression += 'raw_layer_0_unit_%d = sin(dihedral_angle_%d);\n' % (index_of_sins, i)
            expression += 'dihedral_angle_%d = dihedral(p%d, p%d, p%d, p%d);\n' % \
            (i, index_of_backbone_atoms[i], index_of_backbone_atoms[i+1],index_of_backbone_atoms[i+2],index_of_backbone_atoms[i+3])

        return expression

    def write_expression_into_file(self, out_file = None):
        if out_file is None: out_file = self._energy_expression_file

        expression = self.get_expression_of_network()
        with open(out_file, 'w') as f_out:
            f_out.write(expression)
        return

    def get_mid_result(self, input_data=None, connection_between_layers=None, connection_with_bias_layers=None):
        if input_data is None: input_data = self._data_set
        if connection_between_layers is None: connection_between_layers = self._connection_between_layers
        if connection_with_bias_layers is None: connection_with_bias_layers = self._connection_with_bias_layers


        node_num = self._node_num
        temp_mid_result = range(4)
        mid_result = []

        # first need to do preprocessing
        for item in self.mapminmax_preprocess_using_coeff(input_data, self._preprocessing_settings):  
            for i in range(4):
                mul_coef = connection_between_layers[i].params.reshape(node_num[i + 1], node_num[i]) # fix node_num
                bias_coef = connection_with_bias_layers[i].params
                previous_result = item if i == 0 else temp_mid_result[i - 1]
                temp_mid_result[i] = np.dot(mul_coef, previous_result) + bias_coef
                if i != 3: # the last output layer is a linear layer, while others are tanh layers
                    temp_mid_result[i] = map(tanh, temp_mid_result[i])

            mid_result.append(copy.deepcopy(temp_mid_result)) # note that should use deepcopy
        return mid_result

    def get_PC_and_save_it_to_network(self): 
        '''get PCs and save the result into _PCs
        '''
        mid_result = self.get_mid_result()
        self._PCs = [item[1] for item in mid_result]
        return

    def train(self):

        ####################### set up autoencoder begin #######################
        node_num = self._node_num

        in_layer = LinearLayer(node_num[0], "IL")
        hidden_layers = [TanhLayer(node_num[1], "HL1"), TanhLayer(node_num[2], "HL2"), TanhLayer(node_num[3], "HL3")]
        bias_layers = [BiasUnit("B1"),BiasUnit("B2"),BiasUnit("B3"),BiasUnit("B4")]
        out_layer = LinearLayer(node_num[4], "OL")

        layer_list = [in_layer] + hidden_layers + [out_layer]

        molecule_net = FeedForwardNetwork()

        molecule_net.addInputModule(in_layer)
        for item in (hidden_layers + bias_layers):
            molecule_net.addModule(item)

        molecule_net.addOutputModule(out_layer)

        connection_between_layers = range(4); connection_with_bias_layers = range(4)

        for i in range(4):
            connection_between_layers[i] = FullConnection(layer_list[i], layer_list[i+1])
            connection_with_bias_layers[i] = FullConnection(bias_layers[i], layer_list[i+1])
            molecule_net.addConnection(connection_between_layers[i])  # connect two neighbor layers
            molecule_net.addConnection(connection_with_bias_layers[i])  

        molecule_net.sortModules()  # this is some internal initialization process to make this module usable

        ####################### set up autoencoder end #######################


        trainer = BackpropTrainer(molecule_net, learningrate=0.002,momentum=0.4,verbose=False, weightdecay=0.1, lrdecay=1)
        data_set = SupervisedDataSet(node_num[0], node_num[4])

        sincos = self._data_set
        (sincos_after_process, self._preprocessing_settings) = self.get_mapminmax_preprocess_result_and_coeff(data = sincos)
        for item in sincos_after_process:  # is it needed?
            data_set.addSample(item, item)

        trainer.trainUntilConvergence(data_set, maxEpochs=50)

        self._connection_between_layers = connection_between_layers
        self._connection_with_bias_layers = connection_with_bias_layers 

        print("Done!\n")
        return 

    def create_sge_files_for_simulation(self,potential_centers = None):
        if potential_centers is None: 
            potential_centers = self.get_boundary_points()

        neural_network_related.create_sge_files(potential_centers)
        return 

    def get_boundary_points(self, list_of_points = None, num_of_bins = 5):
        if list_of_points is None: list_of_points = self._PCs

        x = [item[0] for item in list_of_points]
        y = [item[1] for item in list_of_points]

        temp = np.histogram2d(x,y, bins=[num_of_bins, num_of_bins])
        hist_matrix = temp[0]
        # add a set of zeros around this region
        hist_matrix = np.insert(hist_matrix, num_of_bins, np.zeros(num_of_bins), 0)
        hist_matrix = np.insert(hist_matrix, 0, np.zeros(num_of_bins), 0)
        hist_matrix = np.insert(hist_matrix, num_of_bins, np.zeros(num_of_bins + 2), 1)
        hist_matrix = np.insert(hist_matrix, 0, np.zeros(num_of_bins +2), 1)

        hist_matrix = (hist_matrix != 0).astype(int)

        sum_of_neighbors = np.zeros(np.shape(hist_matrix)) # number of neighbors occupied with some points
        for i in range(np.shape(hist_matrix)[0]):
            for j in range(np.shape(hist_matrix)[1]):
                if i != 0: sum_of_neighbors[i,j] += hist_matrix[i - 1][j]
                if j != 0: sum_of_neighbors[i,j] += hist_matrix[i][j - 1]
                if i != np.shape(hist_matrix)[0] - 1: sum_of_neighbors[i,j] += hist_matrix[i + 1][j]
                if j != np.shape(hist_matrix)[1] - 1: sum_of_neighbors[i,j] += hist_matrix[i][j + 1]

        bin_width_0 = temp[1][1]-temp[1][0]
        bin_width_1 = temp[2][1]-temp[2][0]
        min_coor_in_PC_space_0 = temp[1][0] - 0.5 * bin_width_0  # multiply by 0.5 since we want the center of the grid
        min_coor_in_PC_space_1 = temp[2][0] - 0.5 * bin_width_1

        potential_centers = []

        for i in range(np.shape(hist_matrix)[0]):
            for j in range(np.shape(hist_matrix)[1]):
                if hist_matrix[i,j] == 0 and sum_of_neighbors[i,j] != 0:  # no points in this block but there are points in neighboring blocks
                    temp_potential_center = [round(min_coor_in_PC_space_0 + i * bin_width_0, 2), round(min_coor_in_PC_space_1 + j * bin_width_1, 2)]
                    potential_centers.append(temp_potential_center)

        return potential_centers

    # this function is added after those old objects of A were created
    def plotting_in_PC_space_with_coloring_option(self, 
                                                  list_of_coordinate_files_for_plotting=None, # accept multiple files
                                                  color_option='pure'):
        '''
        by default, we are using training data, and we also allow external data input
        '''

        if list_of_coordinate_files_for_plotting is None: 
            PCs_to_plot = self._PCs
        else:
            temp_sincos = []
            for item in list_of_coordinate_files_for_plotting:
                temp_sincos += self.get_many_cossin_from_coordiantes_in_file(item)

            temp_mid_result = self.get_mid_result(input_data = temp_sincos)
            PCs_to_plot = [item[1] for item in temp_mid_result]

        (x, y) = ([item[0] for item in PCs_to_plot], [item[1] for item in PCs_to_plot])

        # coloring
        if color_option == 'pure':
            coloring = 'red'
        elif color_option == 'step':
            coloring = range(len(x))

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.scatter(x,y, c=coloring)
        ax.set_xlabel("PC1")
        ax.set_ylabel("PC2")

        plt.show()
        return
```

But it seems that `plotting_in_PC_space_with_coloring_option()` was not binded to those old objects, is here any way to fix it  (I do not want to recreate these objects since creation involves CPU-intensive calculation and would take very long time to do it)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us an example code of what you have tried please.

Comment: Could you show us the code you used when you first tried to bind f()

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes Dang, 29 sec ninja much?

Comment: Yeah, I like it when people help me as soon as possible, so I try to return a favor when I can :)

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes I just updated the question:)

Comment: @warspyking I just updated the question :)

Comment: Umm... you just gave us `class A(Object):` it would help if you gave us an example of you want like functions and an outcome

Comment: It would really help if we could see your code. Could you please upload it.

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes OK, thanks.  I posted all my code now, and you may have a look at the last member function, that is the one I would like to call with those old objects (by saying "old" I mean when they were created the last member function did not exist)

Comment: @TomHehir Sure. I posted all my code now, and you may have a look at the last member function, that is the one I would like to call with those old objects (by saying "old" I mean when they were created the last member function did not exist)

Comment: There is a return statement outside of a function just above defining your new function. Perhaps that is causing issues.

Comment: @TomHehir Oops, this is a copy/paste error.  In my code this is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class A:
    def q(self): print 1

a = A()

def f(self): print 2

setattr(A, 'f', f)

a.f()
```

This is called a `monkey patch`.

Comment: How is ``setattr(A, 'f', f)`` different from ``A.f = f``?

Comment: Following to https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr `setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 123`.

Comment: I meant that rhetorically, as in why not use the much more readable `A.f = f`?

Comment: @Wei Chen the monkey patch method seems like the solution. This thread might help: [Stack Overflow monkey patch thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object)